# Python Password Hidder

Tags: python, authentication, passwords

im working on a Login script in Python, and i want the password to be hidden when i write. I have tried to search around and find a solution, but i cant find anything ...

PS: Iam using mac.

Here is the login script:

```
if (username =='Einar' and password =='Einar2002'):
    print("Login Successfully.")
    os.system("say 'Login Successfully.'")
if not (username =='Einar' and password =='Einar2002'):
    print("Login failed.")
    os.system("say 'Login failed.'")
    exit()
```